# Unity override Coroutine Loop

Tags: unity, c#

I have problem, when i override a Coroutine loop from the base code. But it seems that it only execute once. While on the base code it does what it suppouse to do and that is execute forever.

```
protected virtual IEnumerator OnThink(float interval)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
    }
}

protected override IEnumerator OnThink(float interval)
{
    Debug.Log("Execute");
    yield return StartCoroutine(base.OnThink(interval));
}
```

Comment: Can you show us where you call your overridden version?

Comment: You haven't surrounded the overridden Coroutine in any kind of loop so it will only run the once.

Comment: @DMGregory it's is called from another class.

Comment: @Pheonix2105 could you provide me with an example?

Comment: That's totally OK. We'll accept a relevant code example no matter which class it's sitting in.

Comment: Also, how are you determining how long the overridden version executes for? As written here, it currently has no output other than the log "Execute" when it first starts.

Answer (score 1):

The base method `IEnumerator OnThink`you are overriding, overriding means you want to implement all the logic yourself instead of what the method class provides

```
//base
protected virtual IEnumerator OnThink(float interval)
{

    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
    }
}

//so this function is now overridden meaning it has no logic 
//unless you add it or call the base
//to make it work like the base implementation you just add the while loop
protected override IEnumerator OnThink(float interval)
{
    while(true)
    {

    Debug.Log("Execute");
    yield return StartCoroutine(base.OnThink(interval));
    }
}
```

This particular while loop will run forever since true always will equal true.

while(true) is short for hand for while(true == true) so will run forever, if you add your own boolean for example

```
bool canThink = false;
```

then use that instead of true = true like so

```
    private bool canThink = false;

    protected virtual IEnumerator OnThink(float interval)
   {
     while (true)
     {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
     }
    }

protected override IEnumerator OnThink(float interval)
{
   //for every X interval if canthink is true run the code inside the loop 
   while(canThink == true)
   {
    Debug.Log("Execute");
    //we also just call yield return new WaitForSeconds ourselves
    //in this case there isnt much point in calling the base method.
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
   }
}
```

This way you control the flow of the logic, you can stop and start it just by changing `canThink` - **bare in mind you probably don't want to be calling base in your case as a infinite loop inside a infinite loop will either crash or slow things down a fair bit.**